# Holoviews - how to set legend click_policy for decimated points

Tags: bokeh, holoviews, holoviz, pyviz

I'm trying to set `click_policy` to `'hide'` in `legend_opts` for the object resulted from applying `holoviews.operation.decimate` on a set of `hv.Points`, but it doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

Now I'm using the `muted_alpha` option on the underlying `hv.Points` to hide the points, but this is suboptimal, since hovering over the invisible points still shows the tooltip, which is cluttering the output when showing multiple curves.

I've tried passing `legend_opts={'click_policy': 'hide'}` as `opts` for the `Overlay` container, as well as for both the underlying `hv.Points` and for the result of `decimate` (actually, I also tried passing it as an argument to `decimate`), but to no avail.

I even tried using a hook for the `bokeh` plot as suggested [here](https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/geoviews-and-holoviews-is-it-possible-to-make-the-muted-data-points-unselectable-like-bokeh-does/730/5) to directly set `plot_obj.state.legend.click_policy = 'hide'`, but that doesn't work either.

So, any idea on how to hide a set of `decimate`d `hv.Points` completely (i.e., not showing the hover tooltips either)?

**Note:** I've followed the ["Principles of datashading" section of holoviews' user guide on "Working with large data"](https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Large_Data.html#principles-of-datashading) and used `decimate` as indicated there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that one has to set the options for `hv.Overlay` *after*  calling `collate` on it.